# Git diff for specific folder

Tags: git

I'm listing the files that have changed between 2 different tags

```
git diff --name-only v2.1.1 v2.1.2
```

It results to something like:

```
test/file1
test/file2
www/file3
www/file4
```

Is there any way how I could limit this to list only files that are in www/ folder

Comment: Mhmh... `git diff --name-only v2.1.1 v2.1.2 www/`

Comment: Wierd, I tried this before and got syntax error - maybe I had a typo...

Comment: That is you may add paths to narrow request scope. This works for `git log` and other commands as well

Comment: You may use `v2.1.1..v2.1.2` to specify range or choose a more complex expression like `v2.1.2 --not v2.1.1 ....` Use `man git-rev-list` to get the full docs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the git-diff docs...

```
   git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
       This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.
```

The `--` tells git unambiguously what is a commit and what is a path. So in your case that would be.

```
git diff --name-only v2.1.1 v2.1.2 -- www/
```